# Domain of a multivariable function

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Today I saw an example of finding the domain of a multivariable function. The function in question was this:

$$f(x,y)=\frac{\sqrt{y-x^2}}{1-x^2}$$

The solution:

> For the function, we only want real values so $y$ must be larger than or equal to $x^2$. Also, we can't divide by zero, so $x$ cannot be 1.

They say $x$ cannot be one, since this would be division by 0. But what if we took the point $(1,1)$? Then we would have $\frac{0}{0}$, which is indeterminate. So what's to say we couldn't find that the function is defined at $(1,1)$ after all, by taking some kind of limit to the point? I haven't actually tried to, but that's not the point (no pun intended). **Why is saying that the denominator is zero for $x=1$ sufficient to prove the function is not defined at that point?**

Answer (score 1):

Because $y=1\implies x=\pm 1$ (in the minimum case) which is in turn ruled out by the $x\neq \pm 1$ condition.

Comment: But why do we have the $x \neq 1$ rule in the first place? I get why it applies for when $y \neq 1$ but why does it apply when $y=1$?

Comment: Because the denominator becomes $1-1=0$ which is never defined.

Comment: $\frac{n}{0}$ for non-zero $n$ is never defined, but a limit going to $\frac{0}{0}$ is indeterminate and *can* be defined.

Comment: I see where you're coming from, and thusly your issue. In your question, you're talking about the point $(1,1)$. The function is **not** defined at that point, because $\frac 00$ is not a *specific* value. However. the *limit*, which your comment discusses, *may* exist and could potentially be found. Either way, for a function $f: X\mapsto Y$, the idea that:$$a\notin X \to f(a)=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$$ is totally wrong.

Comment: I still don't understand. Consider the function $sin(x)/x$ for example. At first glance, evaluating the function at zero gives us zero over zero. Does this mean the function is not defined at zero? It does not: We can take a limit to zero and conclude that the function equal 1 at $x=0$.

Comment: No you cannot!!! $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is **NOT** defined at $x=0$. It has a limit as $x\to 0$, but that's why limits exist, to find the values functions approach as they approach values they are not defined for! See [this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vmlimjfwlp), particularly where the graphs intersect.

Comment: Really? Somehow I was not aware of this! Thanks.